# Select Rows without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select only unique rows, without duplicates. In this case, I only want 4 rows returned. How can I remove the duplicates?

```
SELECT 
    d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.DateOfBirth, d.Gender, d.SSN, d.Gender, d.Race, 
    d.HobbyInterest, d.PhysicalDescription, pf.[No of Religious Donations]
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         pf.*, 
         COUNT(Religious) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_Id) as 'No of Religious Donations'
     FROM 
         vw_profileFact pf) pf
JOIN 
    vw_dossier d ON pf.Person_Id = d.Person_Id
WHERE 
    [No of Religious Donations] > 2
ORDER BY 
    [No of Religious Donations] DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: `select distinct...`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT d.FirstName, d.LastName, ...` ? or even better `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pf.*, COUNT(Religious) ...`.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is very bad advice here in my opinion. It's like recommending not to think about what you are doing. It is unnecessary to produce these duplicates, so think of a way to avoid that. (Gordon Linoff shows how in his answer.)

Comment: On a side note: `as 'No of Religious Donations'` is invalid SQL. Single quotes are string literal delimiters. In standard SQL you'd use double quotes for alias names. In SQL Server you'd use brackets.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner no, that SQL is correct. String literals are allowed as alias names (though the format `'alias' = expression` is deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Why are you using window functions?

```
SELECT d.*, pf.num_religious_donations
FROM vw_dossier d JOIN
     (SELECT p.person_id,
             COUNT(p.Religious) AS num_religious_donations
      FROM vw_profileFact p
      GROUP BY p.person_id
     ) pf
     ON pf.Person_Id = d.Person_Id
WHERE num_religious_donations> 2
ORDER BY pf.num_religious_donations DESC;
```

If you want one row per *person*, then aggregation is appropriate.

Comment: In my previous question, you advised me to use windows functions. I didn't think that far ahead on what I will be doing with the data.  Thanks, this works.

Comment: Good answer. I'd only select religous donations in the first place and apply the count condition immediately: `SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS num_religious_donations FROM vw_profileFact WHERE relegious IS NOT NULL GROUP BY person_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2`.

Comment: @Mantas Stanionis: If "Thanks, this works", then accept this answer (by clicking the check/tick sign next to this answer).

Comment: @MantasStanionis . . . Your previous question was stated differently.  Window functions seems appropriate for that.  I did not understand that you wanted one row per person.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.DateOfBirth, d.Gender, d.SSN, d.Gender, d.Race, d.HobbyInterest, 
d.PhysicalDescription, pf.[No_of_Rel_Donations]
FROM (SELECT pf.*, COUNT(Religious) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_Id) as No_of_Rel_Donations
      FROM vw_profileFact pf
     ) pf
JOIN vw_dossier d 
ON pf.Person_Id = d.Person_Id
WHERE [No of Religious Donations] > 2
ORDER BY [No of Religious Donations] DESC;
```

Comment: I get an error 'The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable'.

Comment: @MantasStanionis: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @MantasStanionis - I have edited it, I think this should work now,

Comment: Adding DISTINCT is only hiding a problem in this query instead of solving it, i.e. preventing duplicates in the first place.